# Multiple tables, eliminate data

Tags: sql

Suppose there are three tables `T1`, `T2` and `T3`.

- `T1` has columns `Ordernum` and `bizdate`
- `T2` has columns `Ordernum` and `Orderitem`
- `T3` has columns `Orderitem` and `Catid`

FYI: there are multiple orderitems under each ordernum; each ordertiem has multiple catids.
I want to eliminate ordernums where any itemnum has catid=100.

As I said, each ordernum has multiple orderitem, so I would like to eliminate all orderitem even if only one orderitem in a ordernum has catid=100 .

In other words, I want to print only ordernum where catid != 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery that picks out the orders with that category and use to filter out those orders:

```
select
  OrderNum
from
  T1 as t
where
  not exists(
    select *
    from T1
    inner join T2 on T2.Ordernum = T1.Ordernum
    inner join T3 on T3.Orderitem = T2.Orderitem and T3.Catid = 100
    where T1.Ordernum = t.Ordernum
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to use EXISTS clause:

```
SELECT T1.OrderNum 
FROM T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
     (SELECT * FROM T2 INNER JOIN T3 ON T2.Orderitem = T3.Orderitem
      WHERE T1.OrderNum = T2.OrderNum AND T3.Catid != 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to select all and then exclude them on where statement. I think this will work.

SELECT a1.OrderNum FROM T1 a1
INNER JOIN T2 a2 ON a1.OrderNum = a2.OrderNum
INNER JOIN T3 a3 ON a2.Orderitem = a3.Orderitem
WHERE not a1.OrderNum in
(select ordernum from T2 where orderitem in
  (select Orderitem from T3 where T2.OrderItem = OrderItem and Catid = 100))

or maybe with subjoin is better:

WHERE not a1.OrderNum in
(select sa2.ordernum from T2 sa2 where sa2.orderitem in
  (select sa3.Orderitem
  INNER JOIN T3 sa3 on sa2.OrderItem = sa3.OrderItem and sa3.Catid = 100))

Answer (score 0):

here it is ;

```
select * 
  from T1 
 where ordernum not in (select ordernum 
                          from t2,t3 
                         where t2.Orderitem=t3.Orderitem 
                           and t3.catid=100)
```